# Is it possible to setup Octopress on Windows 7 and Ruby 2.0.0?

Tags: windows-7, ruby-1.9.3, octopress, ruby-2.0

Is it possible to setup Octopress on Windows 7 and Ruby 2.0.0?

Or-  am I forced to install Ruby 1.9.3 ?

I have at work - Windows 7 64.

Thanks...